# What exactly is energy self-shielding in nuclear physics?

Tags: nuclear-physics, terminology, definition, neutrons, nuclear-engineering

I have recently been trying to understand self-shielding, both energy and spatial self-shielding. I am having a particularly hard time understanding energy self shielding. Thus far, everything I’ve been able to find gives an explanation involving energy dependent flux which im not too sure about either. As far as I know, energy self shielding is an important factor in a nuclear reactor that contributes to reactor stability, but why or how this happens is not clear to me at all. If anyone can provide an explanation as to what energy self shielding is and how it works, I’d greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It's explained quite simply but correctly here. For more, you will enter discussions of neutronics specialists who have learned and practice the neutron physics of nuclear reactors.
https://www.nuclear-power.com/nuclear-power/reactor-physics/nuclear-engineering-fundamentals/neutron-nuclear-reactions/self-shielding/

Comment: That’s the website I had initially used to understand energy self shielding. I had trouble understanding the part that mentions a depression in the energy dependent flux. Im not quite sure what that is and I think this is where my confusion mostly lies in.